# Selecting rows for panda dataframe based on a condition

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pycharm

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


lst2 = [[0.23,"f1"],[5.36,'f2']]
lst2_df = pd.DataFrame(lst2,index=list('pd'),columns=list('ab'))
lst2_df = lst2_df.rename({'a':'A'},axis='columns')

print(lst2_df)

m = ['1','f2']
print(lst2_df.loc[lst2_df['b'].isin(m)])
```

If I wish to iterate this condition **for every column** and not hard code it what do I write?
I tried `print(lst2_df.loc[lst2_df['A':'b'].isin(m)])` it didnt worked.
I know there are similar question on the site but I could not find one that addresses my issue.

Comment: Sorry, what is expected output? Do you need `print([lst2_df.loc[lst2_df[c].isin(m)] for c in lst2_df.columns])` ?

Comment: I need that it performs the operation for every column. I have hardcoded it for a column 'b'. If I need to do it for every column,what is the solution? I hope i cleared your doubt

Comment: Can you explain more? What is expected output?

Comment: `print(lst2_df.loc[lst2_df['b'].isin(m)])` is hardcoded for specific column 'b'. Let's say I had a huge dataframe and I wish to print rows whose element matches the condition. `print(lst2_df.loc[lst2_df['all column'].isin(m)])`

Comment: Something like `print(lst2_df.loc[lst2_df.isin(m).any(axis=1)])` ?

Comment: Yes exactly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
m = ['1','f2']
print(lst2_df.loc[lst2_df.isin(m).any(axis=1)])
      A   b
d  5.36  f2
```

Explanation:

Compare `DataFrame` (all columns) by [`DataFrame.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) for boolean:

```
print (lst2_df.isin(m))
       A      b
p  False  False
d  False   True
```

And then add [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for check at least one True per row:

```
print (lst2_df.isin(m).any(axis=1))
p    False
d     True
dtype: bool
```

And last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).

Comment: just one doubt what difference will it make if I use `print(lst2_df.loc[lst2_df.isin(m).all(axis=1)])` instead?

Comment: @user10089194 - It check if all Trues per rows, so filtering only rows with matched all values of m per rows.

Comment: @user10089194 - if use `(lst2_df.isin(m)` get boolean mask. So there is 2 possibility - check if any of value per row is True `.any(axis=1)` or check if all values per row is `True`  by `.all(axis=1)`. So if not all values matched then `.all(axis=1)` return False and output is empty df.

Comment: @user10089194 - try test it by `m = ['1','f2', 5.36]` with sample data

Comment: I did I understood. `.any` is like or. If any of the element matches it will print the entire rows however `.all` is and. All the element should match for it to print the row. That is why in my case it gave Empty dataframe as output. Thanks :)

Comment: If I wish to club two condition is this correct? `print(lst2_df.loc[lst2_df.isin(m).any(axis=1)] & lst2_df.loc[~lst2_df.isin(n).any(axis=1)])`

Comment: No, use `print(lst2_df[lst2_df.isin(m).any(axis=1) & ~lst2_df.isin(n).any(axis=1)])`